# Regex Matching Description part of a JS Doc string

Tags: node.js, regex

I am trying to match the description part (line without a @ symbol) of JS doc string. Here are a couple of exmaples of doc strings.

```
/**
 * This is a doc string
 * @param withArg description of withArg
 * @param withArg2 description of withArg2
 */

/**
 * This is an other doc string
 * This is second line of description.
 */
```

This seems to work in regex editor:
`/\*\S*(.*?)(@)/`
see: https://regexr.com/4dfbn

But in javascript:
https://jsbin.com/qekisogula/1/edit?html,js,console

Any ideas on what is going on ?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE:
Expected output

Example 1:
`This is an other doc string`

Example 2:
`This is an other doc string`, `This is second line of description.`

Comment: What is your expected output, and do you plan to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose? I mean, JSDoc already does a pretty good job of doing all this parsing, and it has a reasonably robust plugin system.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated with expected output. Yes in JS (node.js 8 to be precise)

Comment: @DaveNewton In need this information to make a parser for a use case. Could not find a JS Doc parser stand alone

Comment: @silkAdmin You don't need to, you can use a plugin or a template.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually take the approach of reading the file line by line and using some rudimentary parsing logic:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

var start = false;

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    if (line.startsWith("/**") {
        start = true;
    }
    else if (line.startsWith("*/")) {
        start = false;
    }
    else if (start && !line.includes("@param")) {
        console.log("doc string: ", line);
    }
});
```

The logic here is that we use a boolean flag `start` to keep track of whether we are inside a comment with doc strings.  Upon hitting `/**` the flag is turned on, and upon hitting `*/` the flag is turned off.  If we encounter a line which does *not* contain `@param`, then we echo it to the console.

Comment: Thanks. Couple of things. I am using babel parse and it automatically remove the leading and trailing `/* */` from block comments. So can't really rely on these.
I've update the JSBin with something that works more or less. Could you check it out and let me know what you think https://jsbin.com/cipequbufu/edit?html,js,console

Comment: We need a marker of some sort to know whether a given line belongs to a doc comment or not.  So, I suggest not using your current tool, which makes it very hard to parse the source code.